# Angular JS: ng-repeat with dynamic ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have this **working** piece of code that is repeated multiple times, hence would be great for a ng-repeat loop.
For example, two instances of my code are the following.

```
    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchParamaters.userName" placeholder="User Name"/>
        <i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="resetSearchField(filterParamDisplay[0].param)" ng-show="showParam(filterParamDisplay[0].param)"></i>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchParamaters.userEmail" placeholder="User Email"/>
        <i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="resetSearchField(filterParamDisplay[1].param)" ng-show="showParam(filterParamDisplay[1].param)"></i>
    </div>
```

This is the filterParamDisplay array in Javascript:

```
    $scope.filterParamDisplay = [
        {param: 'userName', displayName: 'User Name'},
        {param: 'userEmail', displayName: 'User Email'}
    ];
```

I have been trying to do that into a ng-repeat loop, but without success so far.
This is what I have coded atm.

```
    <div ng-repeat="param in filterParamDisplay">
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchParams[{{param}}]" placeholder="{{param.displayName}}"/>
        <i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="resetSearchField(filterParamDisplay[$index].param)" ng-show="showParam(filterParamDisplay[$index].param)"></i>
    </div>
```

The problems are into the ng-model variable above, and into the $index in the ng-click and ng-show.
Not sure if this can be done at all, any help is much appreciated, thanks!

---

UPDATE:
Thanks for all the answers, using

```
     <div ng-repeat="p in filterParamDisplay">
...
   ng-model="searchParams[p]"
```

Works great!

Still struggling on the showParam and resetSearchField functions which do not work properly yet using $index. Here is my code.

```
    $scope.searchParams = $state.current.data.defaultSearchParams;

    $scope.resetSearchField = function (searchParam) {
        $scope.searchParams[searchParam] = '';
    };

    $scope.showParam = function (param) {
        return angular.isDefined($scope.searchParams[param]);
    };
```

Comment: You don't need to do `showParam(filterParamDisplay[$index])`.  `ShowParam(param)` itself should work, since `param` is set to that by the `ngRepeat`

Comment: There must be a problem with `searchParams` field. Could you share your js which contains `searchParams` and `resetSearchField`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you bind your ng-models to `searchParameters.userName` and `searchParameters.userMail` at first example, you must use `searchParameters[param.param]` for ng-model in ng-repeat. Also like others said, you don't need to use $index, you got your object as `param` in ng-repeat scope.

```
<div ng-repeat="param in filterParamDisplay">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchParameters[param.param]" placeholder="{{param.displayName}}"/>
    <i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="resetSearchField(param.param)" ng-show="showParam(param.param)"></i>
</div>
```

Here is working **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m8ytbgm6/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-app="dynamicAPP">
    <div ng-controller="dynamicController">
        <div ng-repeat="param in filterParamDisplay">
            <input type="text" ng-model="searchParams[param.param]" placeholder="{{param.displayName}}" /> <i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="resetSearchField(filterParamDisplay[$index].param)" ng-show="showParam(filterParamDisplay[$index].param)"></i>
        </div>{{searchParams}}</div>
</div>
```

[***Jsfiddler link this one for get a single object like 'username' or 'email'***](http://jsfiddle.net/RajamohanShilpa/3tkjyz0r/)

you want single value in ng-show and ng-click use above one. or other wise use belowed one.

```
<div ng-app="dynamicAPP">
    <div ng-controller="dynamicController">
        <div ng-repeat="param in filterParamDisplay">
            <input type="text" ng-model="searchParams[param.param]" placeholder="{{param.displayName}}" /> <i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="resetSearchField(.param)" ng-show="showParam(param)"></i>
        </div>{{searchParams}}</div>
</div>
```

[***Jsfiddler link this one is get whole object based on the control***](http://jsfiddle.net/RajamohanShilpa/vc95gyc3/)

this will passes the whole set of object list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to interpolate angular variables inside `ng-*` directives.

Try:

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="p in filterParamDisplay">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchParams[p]" placeholder="{{p.displayName}}"/>
    <i ng-click="printme(p.param)">click</i>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.filterParamDisplay = [
    {param: 'userName', displayName: 'User Name'},
    {param: 'userEmail', displayName: 'User Email'}
];
$scope.printme = function(v) {
    console.log(v);
};
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dafoo/m8ytbgm6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

As @aarosil said you do not need to use `$index`. 
I wrote a small jsfiddle, I don't know your logic behind showParam so I mocked it.

View :

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="param in filterParamDisplay">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchParams[param.param]" placeholder="{{param.displayName}}"/>
    <i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="resetSearchField(param)" ng-show="showParam(param)"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

and controller :

```
$scope.searchParams = {};  
$scope.filterParamDisplay = [
    {param: 'userName', displayName: 'User Name'},
    {param: 'userEmail', displayName: 'User Email'}
];
$scope.resetSearchField = function(param){
  $scope.searchParams[param.param] = "";
};
$scope.showParam = function(param){ ... }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/29bh7dxe/1/